# Graphs of different orders( at different powers)

Tags: graph-theory

> Given a connected graph $G =(V,E)$ and a positive integer $k$,
>   the k-th power of $G$, denoted $G^k$ , is the graph whose set of
>   nodes is $V$ and where vertices $u$ and $v$ are adjacent in $G_k$ if
>   and only if $d(u,v) \le k$ in $G$.
>
> $P_8$ is a path graph with 8 vertices such as: o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o
>
> $C_{10}$ is a cycle graph: $C_{10}$ has 10 vertices.
>
> $d(u,v)$ is the distance between $u$ and $v$, which is the length of
>   the shortest path $u-v$ from $u$ to $v$ in graph $G$.
>
> I know that two vertices are adjacent in the 2nd power if and only if there's a path of length at most 2 between them in $P_8$.

- Draw the 2-nd and 3-rd powers of $P_8$ and $C_{10}$ .
- For a graph $G$ of order $n$, what is $G^{diam(G)}$

I know the stuff above and I am asking for any answers and help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you the graphs of $P_8^2$ and $P_8^3$, and hopefully this will help you figure out $C_{10}^2$ and $C_{10}^3$. As for the diameter problem, recall that the diameter is the least non-negative integer $d$ such that $d(u,v)\le d$ for all $u,v\in V$. Knowing this and the definition of $G^k$, can you figure out what $G^d$ is?

Here are $P_8^2$ and $P_8^3$.

[image: Graphs of $P_8^2$ and $P_8^3$.]

Comment: I figured out the circular ones, thank you. Regarding the second thing -- Given a graph G=(V,E), $G^d$ is the graph whose set of nodes is V and where vertices u and v are adjacent if and only if $d(u,v)<=d$ in $G$. Is this what $G^d$ is?

Comment: Yes, but which vertices $u,v$ in $G$ satisfy $d(u,v)\le d$ if $d$ is the diameter of $G$ (see definition above)?

Comment: The ones which have the distance lower than the diameter?

Comment: Which ones are those? Are there any that have distance greater than the diameter? Recall that the diameter is the greatest distance between vertices.

Comment: Well the definition says the adjacent but maybe for the diameter it's the opposite.. And yeah there isn't anything greater than the diameter, radius is smaller..

Comment: Well if there are no $u,v$ whose distance is greater than the diameter, then every $u,v$ have distance less than or equal to the diameter, so every $u,v$ are adjacent in $G^d$. So if you have a graph with $n$ vertices and every pair is adjacent, what do you call that graph?

Comment: A complete graph? $K_n$ ?

Comment: Bingo! That's the answer.

Comment: Haha okay so to be straight, $G^d$ is the complete graph whose set of nodes is $V$ and where verttices $u$ and $v$ are adjacent if and only if $d(u,v)<=d$ in $G$, knowing that every pair is adjacent and the distance is less or equal to the diameter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6494/discussion-between-rayradjr-and-max-bummer)